# Apple Watch locks apps because of "App free time"

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

Until 7 am most apps on my Apple Watch can't be used (shown as disabled icons) with the message that it's a app-free time.

I've checked all settings. In the Screen Time screen no limits are set whatsoever. I've disabled/deleted all Focus options.

The settings of my iPhone are set to be synced with my Apple Watch.

Only Screen Time is enabled, because I want to record my actual screen time.

I have no idea how to fix this. I want to be able to use all Apple Watch apps no matter what time it is.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check for since you have screen time on:

- Do you have any "downtime limits"?
- Do you have any app limits on?

  - As of iOS 16, there are two ways this works: whitelist or blacklist.
  - If you have whitelist on, all apps will be limited until you add them to the list. This may be what's happening.
- Turn off screen time and see if it's still happening.
- Restart your watch.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/iphone/iphbfa595995/ios